# Which table does the row come from?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, where-clause

Here is my query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM messages 
WHERE status = 1 
AND (
    poster IN (SELECT thing FROM follows WHERE follower = :uid AND type = 3) 
    OR 
    topic_id IN (SELECT thing FROM follows WHERE follower = :uid AND type = 1)
) 
ORDER BY post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 20
```

I want to know which clause the rows come from. From the `poster IN (...)` part or the `topic_id IN (...)` part? How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A straightforward way:

```
SELECT *
     , CASE WHEN poster IN (SELECT thing FROM follows WHERE follower = :uid AND type = 3) THEN 'poster' 
            ELSE 'topic_id' END AS from_clause
FROM messages <..>
```

Another way :

```
SELECT m.* 
     , CASE WHEN t1.thing IS NULL THEN 'topic_id' ELSE `poster` END AS from_clause
FROM messages m 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT thing FROM follows WHERE follower = :uid AND type = 3) t1 ON m.poster = t1.thing
LEFT JOIN (SELECT thing FROM follows WHERE follower = :uid AND type = 1) t2 ON m.topic_id = t2.thing
WHERE m.status = 1  AND (t1.thing IS NOT NULL OR t2.thing IS NOT NULL)
```

Comment: Thanks but doesn't this slow the query? Let me try.

Comment: @Wellenbrecher : Well, it obviously doesn't speed it up.

Comment: @Wellenbrecher : I've posted another one, haven't tested it, but give it a try.